# Why is my indexedDB.open.onsuccess event not called?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-app, indexeddb

I preface this question with the fact that I am new to working with indexedDB and asynchronous javascript. I am writing a function for a chrome application that takes in an Array buffer called sourceBlob and stores it in indexedDB. The function then opens a data base in indexedDB that I previously created on the applications start up and starts a transaction with that data base.  For some reason when I execute this code request.onsuccess is completely skipped and thus I am not able to add my data to objectStore.  How do I ensure that request.onsuccess is executed? I have read that this issue might be caused by the fact that indexedDB is asynchronous but I have not been able to find an effective solution to this problem.

```
data.indexedDB.addSource = function(sourceBlob) {
//adds source to data base
  var version = 1;
  var request = indexedDB.open("content", version);
  request.onerror = errorHandler;
  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    db = e.target.result;
    var trans = db.transaction(["nContent"], "readwrite");
    var store = trans.objectStore("nContent");
    var request = store.put(sourceBlob);
    trans.oncomplete = function(e) {
      data.indexedDB.getIndexedSource();
    };

  };
};
```

Comment: Maybe the error handler is called instead?

Comment: What do you mean by "skipped"? As you mention asynchrony problems, what do you expect the code to do?

Comment: I checked and the error handler is not called either. The function that I have tied to the onsuccess event is never called. I would expect that once the database is opened the onsucces event would be fired and thus my function that opens the transaction would be executed.

Comment: Is your errorHandler function defined? If not, that could be causing the problem.

Comment: Yes my errorHandler function is defined and functions properly in different parts of my program.

Comment: I don't know y but the only thing worked for me at the end of the day was to change the name of "content" to be something else. And No. I didn't have a db name "content" before.
 

    var request = indexedDB.open("content", version);

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `data.indexedDB.addSource` is being called? Because you can open up your browser's JS console (even on this page) and run this:

```
var request = indexedDB.open("content", 1);
request.onsuccess = function(e) { console.log("onsuccess"); }
```

You will see "onsuccess" displayed.

I suggest you try to make a complete minimal example that shows your problem. In the process of doing so, you'll probably find the solution.

Comment: Yes I am positive that data.indexedDB.addSource is being called. When I step through my function I step into data.indexedDB.addSource however after the function is called the onsuccess or onerror event for opening the database does not get fired.

Comment: Okay, I still suggest you try to make a complete minimal example that shows your problem. The two lines of code I posted work fine on their own. Your entire big codebase doesn't. Rip stuff out of your code until it starts working, and you will find your problem. If you still can't figure it out, post your minimal example code here and it will be easier to help you.

Comment: Hey dumbmatter. I really appreciate your help but I was able to solve the issue.  Since I was opening the database in my function I would exit the function before any event could be fired.  I added a  delay to my function and now my events have time to fire before I exit the function.

Comment: Glad you were able to get it working! Although I suspect there is something else going on, your explanation doesn't sound right and your solution doesn't look like it should do anything.

Comment: If you would like I can send you my code it is pretty short.  I guess what I am doing is blocking from exiting the function until the asynchronous event gets fired, thus making it "act" like a synchronous function.

Answer (score 0):

After working on the app for a while I realized that I was exiting the addSource function before I gave the onsuccess event to fire. To fix this I added a delay at the end of the function and the events now fire properly. Thank you for all of your help. Fixed Code:

```
data.indexedDB.addSource = function(sourceBlob) {
//adds source to data base
  var version = 1;
  var request = indexedDB.open("content", version);
  request.onerror = errorHandler;
  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    db = e.target.result;
    var trans = db.transaction(["nContent"], "readwrite");
    var store = trans.objectStore("nContent");
    var request = store.put(sourceBlob);
    trans.oncomplete = function(e) {
      extron.indexedDB.getIndexedSource();
    };

  };
    var token = 100000;
    while(token != 0)
    {
      token = token-1;

    }
};
```

Comment: there's no way this works, right? javascript is usually all single threaded.

Comment: This is completely wrong.  I have no idea what was actually happening (not going to try to solve somebody's problem from 2014), but if you've searched your way here, don't copy this.

Answer (score 0):

(My answer maybe irrelevant to OP's question, but maybe helpful to someone who just picked up indexedDB, and not familiar with javascript)

Make sure your handler is registered in the same epoch which request object are created (especially in console, you should type multiple lines of code and execute them at once, instead of saving the request and bind handlers later).

Unlike DOM elements like `Image` which allows you to register handler before actually fire the request:

```js
let i = new Image();
i.onload = (e)=>{ console.log("image is loaded"); }
i.src = "some/url.png";
```

indexedDB requests are fired when they are made, and the call to handler(which is registered "later") is ensured by javascript concurrency model.

```js
var request = indexedDB.open("test", 1);
// request may already done at this point, 
// however, the event is delayed to next javascript epoch, 
// so you can register the handler after `request` is created.
// and ensure the handler is called.

request.onsuccess = function(e) { console.log("onsuccess"); }
request.onerror = function(e) { console.log("onerror"); }
```